# Duplicate files with the server name on a File Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, files, file-server, deduplication

For some time it has been happening to me that in a file server, where I have a shared folder with the departments of the company, in some folders it has been duplicating some files by adding the name of the server to final.
It does not happen constantly, but recently a person was working with an outdated file, that is, it was not the last modified.
This happens with Word, Excel, image files.
For example, the server is named SRV07 and adds that name to the file at the end.

annex.png
annex-SRV07.png

I appreciate your collaboration.

Thanks you
Best regards

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like OneDrive is involved. Is it?